# Image with link doesn't change size when parent does

Tags: html, css, anchor

I have this HTML code:

```
<header>
    <a href="index.php"><img src="..\images\logo.svg" alt=""></a>
</header>
```

and this CSS:

```
header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 110px;
    background-color: #4e4d4d;
    padding: 0em 3em;
}

header img {
    width: 37%;
}
```

When I decrease the `header` height shouldn't the img also shrink? Can somebody please tell what should I do in order to achieve that?
Thank you

Comment: `header img { width: 37%; height: auto; display: block; }` - give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

You can make `height: 100%` but maybe that might distort the image. You can remove `width` to keep aspect ratio of original image. How would you like to account for the smaller height?

```css
header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 110px;
  background-color: #4e4d4d;
  padding: 0em 3em;
}

header img {
  width: 37%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="index.php"><img src="https://picsum.photos/64" alt=""></a>
</header>
```